# Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug' in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, gradle

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

```
      When developing App I get this error and I could not able to Run the App. My build is getting Successful. But I could not run the App. Please provide me information to solve this........
```

And I am getting this exception while build the app

AAPT err(1229713066): C:\Users\rramnath143729\AndroidStudioProjects\Appathon_app\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\ic_drawer.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(2016822147): C:\Users\rramnath143729\AndroidStudioProjects\Appathon_app\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\ic_drawer.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(949986979): C:\Users\rramnath143729\AndroidStudioProjects\Appathon_app\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\ic_drawer.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(949986979): C:\Users\rramnath143729\AndroidStudioProjects\Appathon_app\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.0.0\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited

Note: C:\Users\rramnath143729\AndroidStudioProjects\Appathon_app\app\src\main\java\com\amat\rramnath143729\appathon_app\NavigationDrawerFragment.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

And when I looked into the build.gradle file, I find cannot resolve the symbol 'getDefaultProguardFile'-----

buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

Comment: Kindly Edit your Question...

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand if you have an actual question, but regarding the AAPT err, this might help: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77704

I'm actualy downloading ImageMagick to try to update my PNG files, which should help get rid of this error.